# USB headset Surround Sound 7,1

Tags: sound, usb, headset

I recently bought a surround 7.1 USB headset, but in settings, nothing shows up(I tried going to settings, because when I connected a Bluetooth speaker, it gave me a choice). I'm using a Yenkee SABOTAGE headset, and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It is unclear is the headset Bluetooth?

Comment: No, in the title i mentioned its a USB headset

Comment: There are only two drivers so 7.1 is just marketing gimmick.  Any "7.1 surround" would be a result of *software* trying to emulate surround sound using two speakers. Software would need to be compatible with Linux.  Does the manufacturer support the device's software features on Linux?